# search through files and put into array

Tags: linux, terminal, find, cat

```
cat `find . -name '*.css'`
```

This will open any css file. I now what do two things.

1) How do I add *.js to this as well. So I want to look inside all css and javascript files.

2) I want to look for any css or image files within those (css or js files) and push those into an array. So I guess look for a .png, .jpg, .gif, .tif, .css and put everything before that until the quote or single quote into an array. I want an array because this command will go into a shell script and after I get all the names of the files that I need I will need to loop through and download those files later.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Extra hackery, in case someone needs it:

```
find ./ -name "*.css" | xargs grep -o -h -E '[A-Za-z0-9:./_-]+\.(png|jpg|gif|tif|css)'| sed -e 's/\.\./{{url here}}/g'|xargs wget
```

will download every missing resource

Answer (score 1):

Do the command:

```
find ./ -name "*.css" -or -name "*.js" > fileNames.txt
```

Then read each line of fileNames.txt in the loop and download them.

Or if you are going to use wget to download the images you could do:

```
find ./ -name "*.css" -or -name "*.js" | xargs grep '*.png' | xargs wget
```

May need a little refinement like a `cut` after the `grep` but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

1) simple answer: you can add the names of all .js files to your `cat` command, by instructing `find` to find more files:

```
cat `find . -name '*.css' -or -name '*.js'`
```

2) a text-searching tool such as `grep` is probably what you're after:

```
find . -name '*.css' -or -name '*.js' | xargs grep -o -h -E '[A-Za-z0-9:./_-]+\.(png|jpg|gif|tif|css)'
```

Note: my grep pattern isn't universal or perfect, but it's a starting example.  It matches any string that includes alpha-numeric,colon,dot,slash,underscore or hyphens in it, followed by any one of the given extensions.

The `-o` option causes grep to output only the parts of the .css/.js files that match the pattern (i.e. only the apparent filenames).

If you want to download them you could add `| xargs wget -v` to the command, which would instruct `wget` to fetch all those filenames.
***NOTE***: this won't work for relative filenames; some other magic will be required (i.e. you'll have to resolve them with respect to the grepped file's location).  Perhaps some extra hackery, such as `sed` or `awk`.

Also: How often do you see references to TIFFs in your CSS/JS?

Comment: @Matty_K this is almost perfect. ./example.com-saved/example.com/tipsy.js:tip.css. It is giving me the directory name it is in and then a colon and then the filename. I would like to have just the filename. Anyway to get that? TIFFs not really used anymore but I thought I would throw it in for good measure.

Comment: @rich I believe adding `-h` to the grep command gets rid of that tipsy.js filename. Updated.

Comment: Wow that is pretty amazing. That you very much. So much to learn!

Comment: @rich I'll let you in on a secret: I don't know very much, I just typed `man grep` and read the manual.